# How do i open multiple socket connections in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, mobile

I am porting an app i have written for android to ios and i am having trouble opening more than 1 connection to my server. My android app uses 2 sockets to connect to my server (my server is listening at ports 4444 and 4445) and both are needed to transmit different types of data back and forth.
In swift i tried doing this:

```
        var inp : NSInputStream?
        var out : NSOutputStream?

        var inStreamUnmanaged:Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var outStreamUnmanaged:Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, host, UInt32(port), &inStreamUnmanaged, &outStreamUnmanaged)
        var inStreamUnmanaged2:Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var outStreamUnmanaged2:Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, host, UInt32(port2), &inStreamUnmanaged2, &outStreamUnmanaged2)
        inp = inStreamUnmanaged?.takeRetainedValue()
        out = outStreamUnmanaged?.takeRetainedValue()

        out!.open()
        inp!.open();

        let str = "Hello"
        var x = [UInt8](str.utf8)
        out!.write(&x, maxLength: x.count)

        var readByte :UInt8 = 0
        while inp!.hasBytesAvailable {
            inp!.read(&readByte, maxLength: 1)
        }
```

To connect to my server:

```
                    clientSocket =serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("0-new connection");
                nSocket = nSSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("1-new connection");
```

However only the first message is printed in the server console. I double checked the secondary port's value in swift and it is indeed 4445 and everything looks correct. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var inp : NSInputStream?
    var out : NSOutputStream?

    var inStreamUnmanaged:Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var outStreamUnmanaged:Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, host, UInt32(port), &inStreamUnmanaged, &outStreamUnmanaged)

// YOU never use this in your code !!!
    var inStreamUnmanaged2:Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var outStreamUnmanaged2:Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?


    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, host, UInt32(port2), &inStreamUnmanaged2, &outStreamUnmanaged2)
    inp = inStreamUnmanaged?.takeRetainedValue()
    out = outStreamUnmanaged?.takeRetainedValue()

    out!.open()
    inp!.open();

    let str = "Hello"
    var x = [UInt8](str.utf8)
    out!.write(&x, maxLength: x.count)

    var readByte :UInt8 = 0
    while inp!.hasBytesAvailable {
        inp!.read(&readByte, maxLength: 1)
    }
```

...

```
var inp2 : NSInputStream?
var out2 : NSOutputStream?
.....
inp2 = inStreamUnmanaged2?.takeRetainedValue()
out2 = outStreamUnmanaged2?.takeRetainedValue()
.....
// and use it!
```

The underlying connection is NOT created until you open the stream

Comment: it doesnt work. the second connection is supposed to be created at CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, host, UInt32(port2), &inStreamUnmanaged2, &outStreamUnmanaged2) and the server should print the second message. i didnt do what you said on purpose since it doesnt matter anyways

Comment: the server is not able to print nothing if you don't use the streams! open inp2, open out2 and write there something. if you check just the listening part, open the stream should be enought

Comment: @Kores creating stream does't make connection to your server. the connection is created when you open the associated stream, in your case there are inp2 resp. out2.

Comment: tyvm! didnt know about that :)

Comment: @Kores it is mentioned in apples doc, isn't it? anyway, nice to help you!